# indexing into an octave array using another array

Tags: arrays, matlab, multidimensional-array, matrix, octave

Hi I have an three dimensional octave array A of size [x y z]

Now I have another array B of dimensions n * 3

say B(0) gives [3 3 1]

I need to access that location in A ie A(3, 3, 1) = say 15
something like A(B(0))

How do I go about it?

Answer (score 0):

See the help for `sub2ind` (and `ind2sub`).
However, nowadays people recommend to use loops.

Answer (score 0):

Well, first, `B(0)` is invalid index, as addressing in MATLAB and Octave begins from 1. Other issue is that you want that `B(0)` would contain a vector `[3 3 1 ]`. Matrices in MATLAB can not contain other matrices, only scalars. So you need to use a 3x3 cell array, a 3x3 struct or a 4-dimensional array. I'll choose here the cell array option, because I find it easiest and most convenient.

% Set random seed (used only for example data generation).

```
rng(123456789);
```

% Let's generate some pseudo-random example data.

```
A = rand(3,3,3);

A(:,:,1) =
0.5328    0.7136    0.8839
0.5341    0.2570    0.1549
0.5096    0.7527    0.6705

A(:,:,2) =
0.6434    0.8185    0.2308
0.7236    0.0979    0.0123
0.7487    0.0036    0.3535

A(:,:,3) =
0.1853    0.8994    0.9803
0.7928    0.3154    0.5421
0.6122    0.4067    0.2423
```

% Generate an example 3x3x3 cell array of indices, filled with pseudo-random 1x3 index vectors.

```
CellArrayOfIndicesB = cellfun(@(x) randi(3,1,3), num2cell(zeros(3,3,3)), 'UniformOutput', false);
```

% Example #1. Coordinates (1,2,3).

```
Dim1 = 1;
Dim2 = 2;
Dim3 = 3;
```

% The code to get the corresponding value of A directly.

```
ValueOfA = A(CellArrayOfIndicesB{Dim1,Dim2,Dim3}(1), CellArrayOfIndicesB{Dim1,Dim2,Dim3}(2), CellArrayOfIndicesB{Dim1,Dim2,Dim3}(3));
ValueOfA =
         0.8839
```

% Let's confirm that by first checking where CellArrayOfIndicesB{1,2,3} points to.

```
CellArrayOfIndicesB{1,2,3}
ans =
    [ 1 3 1 ]
```

% `CellArrayOfIndicesB{1,2,3}` points to `A(1,3,1)`.
% So let's see what is the value of `A(1,3,1)`.

```
A(1,3,1)
ans =
    0.8839
```

% Example #2. Coordinates (3,1,2).

```
Dim1 = 3;
Dim2 = 1;
Dim3 = 2;

ValueOfA = A(CellArrayOfIndicesB{Dim1,Dim2,Dim3}(1), CellArrayOfIndicesB{Dim1,Dim2,Dim3}(2), CellArrayOfIndicesB{Dim1,Dim2,Dim3}(3));
ValueOfA =
         0.4067

CellArrayOfIndicesB{3,1,2}
ans =
    [ 3 2 3 ]

A(3,2,3)
ans =
    0.4067
```